# Set an image background according to a data field in the div using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to set the background image of a bunch of divs that all have the same class name.  But I want each div to have a different background image. Here is what I came up with:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="element-item" data-img="imageName.svg">
    <h3 class="name">Name</h3>
    <p class="symbol">&</p>
    <p class="number">#</p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// DOM is ready here

    $("div.element-item").each(function(){

        $(this).css({"background-image", "url("+"/path/[data-img]"+")"});

    });
});

$(this).css({"background-image"**, "url("+"/fabric/images/[data-img]"+")"});**
```

**Error:**

> Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , on

Comment: You have curly bracks on your `.css`. It should look like this $(this).css("background-image", "url("+"/path/[data-img]"+")");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first issue is that you need to concatenate the `data` attribute. You can't include it within a string by doing `[data-img]` as you have.

Additionally, the jQuery [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function takes two different types of arguments: You can either do `.css(property, value)` or `.css({property:value, property:value, ... })`. You seem to have mixed these two and are passing it an object where it's `{property,value}` instead.

```
$("div.element-item").each(function(){
    var imgUrl = "/path/" + $(this).data("img");
    $(this).css("background-image", "url(" + imgUrl + ")");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good way to start using the .attr function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("div.element-item").each(function(){
            var $dataImage=$(this).attr("data-img");  //notice the .attr function
            $(this).css("background-image", "url('/path/" + $dataImage + "')");

      });
 });
```

Comment: `$data-image` needs to be concatenated in the url string, you will not be able to use the variable that way. Not my downvote.

Comment: Hey @Brian. There are multiple issues with this answer (and the code). First off, it doesn't tell OP why his answer is wrong or explain what you've fixed - it's a game of "spot the difference". Second, variable names cannot have `-` in JavaScript so none of the code will work. Third, the variables are declared in the global scope (without a `var` declaration) which should never be a suggestion (not to mention the `$` here is misleading). Finally it's missing a `)}`. Code-only answers are rarely *good* answers, but if you're going to post one, please at least run it to make sure it works.

Comment: I've removed my downvote. Just please note that in JavaScript, declaring a variable without the word `var` makes it *global*, and you usually want to keep your global scope as clean as possible. Additionally, the `$` before a variable name usually indicates that it's a jQuery object - but in your code it is a simple `string`. Lastly, your CSS property is going to render as `url('/path/'image-name.svg);` with single quotes around the path only. Thanks for editing :)

Comment: Sorry.  Edited once again!

Comment: Much better! +1

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) to access your data-img attribute.

You **cannot** add the data attribute using `[data-img]` in your string concatenation. Use the *.data("img")* method to fetch the data-img attribute value and add to the string.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// DOM is ready here

$("div.element-item").each(function(){
    var dataImage = '/path/' + $(this).data('img');
    $(this).css("background-image", "url(" + dataImage + ")");

});
```